# Display flex and justify content in Elementor

Tags: css, wordpress, flexbox, elementor

I am trying to make a header in elementor using display: flex and Justify-content: space-between to place the elements where I want them to be. But I can't get it to work, justify-content does nothing when applied.

You can see the menu in this link, all colors are just to make it more visible while I get it to work.

https://wireframe.dk/

Each column has an ID and the section has the class .overlay. I want to make equal space between those columns.

Is there a problem with using display: flex in elementor or is it the justify-content that doesn't work? Or am I just missing something.

The CSS I use is included here:

```
    .overlay{
        background: grey;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 90px;
        z-index: 10;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    #logo{
        width: 180px;
        height: 90px;
        background: #464646;
        flex-grow: 0;
    }

    #menu-actions{
        width: 180px;
        height: 90px;
        background: red;
        transition: .6s;
        flex-grow: 0;
    }

    #menu-actions:hover{
        background: blue;
        width: 225px;
    }

    #menu-user{
        width: 90px;
        height: 90px;
        background: yellow;
        transition: .6s;
        flex-grow: 0;
    }

    #menu-user:hover{
        width: 135px;
        background: green;
    }

    #menu-shop{
        height: 90px;
        width: 180px;
        background: orange;
        transition: .6s;
        flex-grow: 0;
    }

    #menu-shop:hover{
        width: 225px;
        background: purple;
    }
```

Comment: You need something like that: https://pasteboard.co/K9s58CJ.png ?

Comment: They are not supposed to fill the whole header section, they need to be the width in the css and then just have space between them. Like this: https://wireframe.dk/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Skaermbillede-2021-07-03-kl.-14.03.17.png